# How to have the list of files represented by a regex given in input to a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm creating a code for the automatic extraction of `bib` records from scientific papers.

In an old version of the script i gave in input the name of the folder where all the pdfs were stored, now I want to give a regex. E.g. before:

`./AutoBib.sh Papers/`

Now:

`./Autobib.sh Papers/*.pdf`

In the folder there are, for example 3 pdf files: Shrek.pdf, Fiona.pdf, Donkey.pdf, using my script I should be able to retrieve the doi from all files creating a file where all doi are listed but executing my script it returns the doi of the **first** file and nothing more.

Here there is my code:

```
for i in $1; do
    doi $i
done
```

*doi* is a function that extract the doi from a pdf and puts it in a txt file. When i run the script it returns me only the doi of the first file.

How can I feed a regex in my script and being able to iterate though all files that matches that regex?

Answer (score 3):

It's important to understand that `Papers/*.pdf` is not a regular expression, it's  a wildcard pattern that causes `bash` to perform filename expansion, or [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html).

`$1` represents the first argument to your script, so your `for` loop is only ever iterating over that one argument.

Use `$@` to represent all arguments:

```
for i in "$@"; do
    doi "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter files within directory by pattern, you can pass this pattern as second script parameter and search for matching files using `find`.

Here is the code. It's additionally resistant to filenames containing spaces:

```
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -name "$2" -exec doi {} \;
```

Usage example: `./Autobib.sh Papers/ *.pdf`

Comment: This has multiple problems. You [don't want to use `ls` in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and `*.pdf` is not a valid regex.  Even if it were, you'd need to quote it in order to prevent the shell from expanding it into a list of arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I edited answer to use `find` instead of `ls` and to make description more relevant.

Comment: `read` is still not robust, you want something like `while IFS="" read -r filename` but a much better solution is `find ... -exec doi {} j;`

Comment: Yeah, looks great to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just run the `ls` command in loop and it will solve your problem.

```
for x in $(ls $@/*.pdf)
do
echo $x  ## if you want only file name you can change this line to echo `basename $x`
done
```

I have created the same scenario as you mentioned above, refer the snapshot.

[image]